# I am developing a SOAP client with Apache CXF. when execute my service it returns me this stack in the client

Tags: soap, cxf

Stack trace:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not parse message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:143)


Caused by: org.codehaus.stax2.typed.TypedXMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,603]
Message: Element content can not contain child START_ELEMENT when using Typed Access methods
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader._constructTypeException(BasicStreamReader.java:5482)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader._constructUnexpectedInTyped(BasicStreamReader.java:5475)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getElementText(BasicStreamReader.java:658)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:658)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2139)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2022)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1947)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:472)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:123)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: please share your configurations for CXF.

Comment: there is no specific configurations done for CXF other than generating stubs using CXF and integrated with my application for calling service. Using CXF generated stub, i have set security and request headers and then endpoint, and then passed my request data to invoke. Am i missing something?

Comment: Ok. The stack trace says that it cannot parse the message. There would be some wsdl you would be using to generate the request XML. Something is wrong with that XML maybe.can you share that?